# move some variable from one php page to onother and move between to page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm new at php. I get the last id from database. For each id I want the state and the link. I'll check if `state == 1`, then get the content of the link (there's JavaScript variable that I need that is in the content of link). I'll send that variable with `location.href`.

Then I get that variable with `$_GET` in the second page. I want to store that var into database, then come back to first page and get the second link from the database and again do the same works.

How can I send the `$j` into second page for saving the `x_cor` and `y_cor`, and how to increase the `$j` when it comes to first page again?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>firstpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    include_once ('simple_html_dom.php');

    include_once ('split_unicode_function.php');

    // getting the last id from db

    $connection = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "kkuser");
    $select_db = mysql_select_db("kk", $connection);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM netbarg ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $last_id = $rows['id'];

    // getting id and link for each column

    for ($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++)
        {
        $select_db = mysql_select_db("kk", $connection);
        $id = "SELECT state FROM `table`  WHERE id='$j' ";
        $result = mysql_query($id, $connection);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo $state = $row[0] . '<br />';

        // getting link

        $link = "SELECT link FROM `table`  WHERE id='$j' ";
        $result = mysql_query($link, $connection);
        $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $link = $rows[0];

        // (state is just 1 or 2)check if the state is 2 or not...

        if ($state == 1)
            {
            $f = file_get_contents($link);
            echo "<div>$f</div>";
            }
        }

    ?>
      <script>
         $("body").hide();
         location.href ='secondpage.php?val='+point0+;
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**second page**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>second page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['val']))
        {
        $hat = $_GET['val'];
        echo $hat;
        $coords = trim($hat, '()');

        // echo $coords.'<br />';

        $a = array();
        $a = explode(",", $coords);
        var_dump($a);
        echo $long = $a[0];
        echo '<br />';
        if ($long == "undefined") $lat = "undefined";
          else echo $lat = $a[1];
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")
            {
            $connection = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "kkuser");
            $select_db = mysql_select_db("kk", $connection);
            $update = "UPDATE `table` SET `x_cor`='$long',`y_cor`='$lat'  ,      `state`='2'  WHERE `id`='$j' ";
            $insert_todb = mysql_query($update, $connection);
            if ($insert_todb) echo "coordinates has been updated", '<br />';
            }
        }

    ?>
    <script>
        location.href ='firstpage.php';
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at AJAX and/or sessions.

Comment: Sessions would help with this. http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php. Start with the introduction.

Comment: Sorry, but your description makes little sense to me. Since you are loading the links via JS, there seems to be no user interaction involved here - so why switch between different scripts in the first place, instead of doing it all in one script? Can you please describe what end result you want to achieve here?

Comment: i have a column that name is state (it can be 1 or 2).i want to check the state column for each link.if it was 2 it means that the x_cor and y_cor of that link are saved in database.if not i want to get the point0 variable from the content of that page and save it and come back to first page and again do it for another pages.

Answer (score 0):

if get the last insert id use mysqli_insert_id($con); 
it return last insert id from database using this geted id you can